# Transparency to unique value in ArcGIS 10.3

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, symbology, transparency-opacity, definition-query

I have this polygon layer and i try to set the transparency to 52% only to the c value:

[image]

[image]

but when i set to 52% transparency, all the values changed:

[image]

I can copy\paste the polygon and remove a,b values and then set the transparency to 52% , but i prefer not using this method.

Answer (score 2):

To do this I would take a copy of the layer, and then set complementary Definition Queries on the two layers so that you can set transparency on the features appearing in one layer while leaving those in the other layer opaque.

Answer (score 0):

I think the [solution from PolyGeo](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/202433/115) is the best and you could group the layers fo a better handling.

Another, but maybe not so nice alternative is to use a `MarkerFillSymbol` instead, with a narrow **raster** in the wished colour. This lets shine through and brings a bit transparency.